# Getting size of std::vector (by extending variadic template functions working exclusively with parameter types to work with arguments)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm trying to extend code that calculates size of template pack types to be able to get size of a `std::vector<T>` instance (my notion of the size of a vector is `std::vector<T>::size() * sizeof(T)`). Here is the original code:

```
template <class T>
constexpr size_t getSize_single()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}

// specialized case
template<>
constexpr size_t getSize_single<double>()
{
    return SIZEOF_DOUBLE;
}

template <class... Ts>
size_t getSize()
{
    // handles the case of Ts being empty
    std::initializer_list<size_t> l{getSize_single<Ts>()...};
    size_t sum = 0;
    for(auto s : l) sum += s;
    return sum;
}
```

I use it like

```
template <class ...T>
void foo(T... arg)
{
    std::cout << getSize<T...>() << std::endl;
}

// main
foo(11.123456789, 1.12345, 2.12345, 3.12345);
```

My take on extending it to work with `std::vector<T>` was the following:

Since we need to get size of an instance of `std::vector<T>`, we need to have access to it, which we achieve by passing it to `getSize()`, which changes it to

```
template <class ...T>
void foo(T... arg)
{
    std::cout << getSize(arg...) << std::endl;
}

// main
foo(11.123456789, std::vector<double>{1.12345, 2.12345, 3.12345});
```

Then

```
template <class T>
constexpr size_t getSize_single()
{
    return sizeof(T);
}

template<>
constexpr size_t getSize_single<double>()
{
    return SIZEOF_DOUBLE;
}

// arg_tag_val<T> hack for std::vector to work

template <typename T> struct arg_tag_val {const T &t;};

template <class T>
constexpr size_t getSize_single(arg_tag_val<T>)
{
    return getSize_single<T>();
}

template<>
constexpr size_t getSize_single<double>(arg_tag_val<double>)
{
    return getSize_single<double>();
}

template<>
constexpr size_t getSize_single<float>(arg_tag_val<float>)
{
    return getSize_single<float>();
}

template <class T>
size_t getSize_single(arg_tag_val<std::vector<T>> v)
{
    return v.t.size() * getSize_single<T>();
}

template <class... Ts>
size_t getSize(const Ts&... arg)
{
    // handles the case of Ts being empty
    std::initializer_list<size_t> l{getSize_single<Ts>(arg_tag_val<Ts>{arg})...};
    size_t sum = 0;
    for(auto s : l) sum += s;
    return sum;
}
```

But it fails short, because in the bottom `getSize` function `Ts` is `std::vector<double>` and `getSize_single` gets called as `getSize_single<std::vector<double>>(arg_tag_val<std::vector<double>>{vec})`, which calls `constexpr size_t getSize_single(arg_tag_val<T>)` instead of `size_t getSize_single(arg_tag_val<std::vector<T>> v)`.

I got stuck here and not sure how to make it work, thus asking for help.

I'm restricted to C++11.

Comment: separate concerns: do the runtime size calculation with ordinary functions. check if you still need compile time size (you don't get that for the vector).

Comment: Is the size of this vector a constant known at compile time? If so, you want to use an `std::array`.

Comment: @Pradhan Nope, not constant.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That's exactly what I'm asking for -- runtime calculation.

Comment: @FlyingHat: in that case, why don't you just equip the `getSize` function with a runtime argument. One that does't try to be compile-time in any way. Just a reference of the relevant type. ;-) If that works, and it should, then please impersonate me and convert this comment to an answer, and, reverting to your original SO login, upvote it and select it as solution.

Comment: Right, that's how I got it working -- with a simple argument. I over-engineered things a bit in the question with that `arg_tag_val`. There is another issue though, which still is present in the example shown in the original question. I will edit the question to point directly at the issue, removing this `arg_tag_val` madness.

Comment: Actually, I realized something and fixed it while editing the answer, so there is no issues at all. Will self-answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my first take on it was totally over-engineered. If we get rid of `arg_tag_val` argument wrapper and use the actual argument, then everything works just fine.

```
template <class T>
size_t getSize_single(T&)
{
    return sizeof(T);
}

// specialized case
template<>
size_t getSize_single<double>(double&)
{
    return SIZEOF_DOUBLE;
}

template <class T>
size_t getSize_single(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    size_t size = 0;

    if (v.size() > 0) {
        size += v.size() * getSize_single(v[0]);
    }

    return size;
}

template <class... Ts>
size_t getSize(Ts&... arg)
{
    // handles the case of Ts being empty
    std::initializer_list<size_t> l{getSize_single(arg)...};
    size_t sum = 0;
    for(auto s : l) sum += s;
    return sum;
}
```

Although Cheers and hth. - Alf commented on my question describing exactly this code, I wrote it myself before seeing the comment.